# How to find a file path like `\\company\path` while in edit mode in a browser editor like confluence

Tags: browser, find-and-replace, wildcards, escape-characters, confluence

When editing a page in confluence `CTRL`-`f` brings you to a find-and-replace dialogue instead of the find field of your browser. When filling in a file path in the find box of this dialogue, you don't find that file path.

I assume this is because backslash is an escape character, so I tried doubling the back slashes, but that does not work. Replacing them by typical wild chard characters, like `*`, `.` or `?` does not work either.

Does anyone have a sollution?

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-search-syntax-158720.html):

> Note: Confluence doesn't support leading wildcards. This means searching for *heese will not return cheese.

So, if you search for `\\company\path`, `*company?path` will not return anything.

I'd use: `company?path`, without the leading wildcard.

Comment: As I wrote, the `?` wild card does not work. Should I flag somewhere I want to use wildcards first?

Comment: @DirkHorsten: Have you tried to search with regex, like: `/\\\\company\\path/` or `/.*company\\path.*/`

Comment: I just tried, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the find facility without pressing `ctrl`-`f`:

- In Google, in the right upper corner, under the windows close-cross, you find 3 dots that open a menu. This menu includes the find facility of google.
- In Internet Explorer, at the same place, you can open the settings menu. The submenu `File` contains a `find on this page` option;